# 18.04: USB optical drive not recognized on Gigabyte Z390

Tags: hardware, devices, usb-c, gigabyte

I have just installed 18.04 on a custom built new htpc with a Gigabyte Aorus Z390 I mainboard and would like to connect my external cd-drive via a USB type-C port. My optical drive only has USB-output (type-A port) and the manufacturer (Melco) has confirmed that the setup works (at least with Win 10).

Now, Ubuntu doesn't recognize the device at all and as a complete Ubuntu-newbie, I simply don't know what to do.

Is there a way to check to that the USB-C port is working? I don't have Windows running on the htpc, only Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

There are [17 different Gigabyte AORUS Z390](https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Motherboard/Intel-Z390) motherboards; you did not mention which you have.

They have one thing in common: The USB-C port requires a special driver to work. They do not provide a Linux driver, [only a Windows driver](https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Motherboard/Z390-AORUS-PRO-rev-10/support#support-dl-driver) as shown for the AORUS Z390 Pro.

You will need to use one of their USB 3.0 ports instead for that external optical drive.

Selecting hardware before purchase where all features are supported by Ubuntu prevents a lot of heartburn.

Comment: Thanks for solving that issue. I tried to check Ubuntu's hardware support but obviously failed to find the correct information. And Gigabyte doesn't provide any drivers for Linux, it seems. Yes, there are many Z390 mainboards but only one Z390 I, as far as I know.